# Information_Schema on oracle?

Tags: oracle, information-schema

I'm a SQL Server DBA, and I like to mess around with Oracle here and there.

I can see with `select * from information_Schema.columns` everything about a table (everything that I need now).

Is there a way to list these informations on a Oracle Schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent in Oracle is `user_tab_columns` for tables **owned** by the current user or [`all_tab_columns`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F218205C-7D76-4A83-8691-BFD2AD372B63.htm#REFRN20277) for tables *accessible* to the current user.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can view such information in [Data Dictionary and Dynamic Performance Views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/data-dictionary-and-dynamic-performance-views.html#GUID-BDF5B748-EB43-4B48-938E-89099069C3BB).

For information about table columns, you can use the view [DBA_TAB_COLS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/DBA_TAB_COLS.html#GUID-857C32FD-AE30-4AB9-811B-AC3A7B91A04D).

```
select * from dba_tab_cols;
```

Comment: Regular users typically do not have access to DBA_xxx views